# Can Lazarus 64-bit for Windows compile to 64-bit for Windows?

Tags: windows, 64-bit, lazarus

I downloaded, what i thought, would be the 64-bit version of Lazarus:

[image]

Although it downloads a 32-bit build:

[image]

And after installing it, the IDE is 32-bits:

[image]

And it builds 32-bit binaries:

[image]

Changing the targeting options to *win64*, *win64*, *win64*:

[image]

Gives an error that Lazarus doesn't support 64-bit:

[image]

Reading the somewhat dated [**Cross compiling Wiki page**](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Cross_compiling#From_win32_to_win64) gives the instructions on how to make the 64-bit Lazarus work on 64-bit machines:

> ### From win32 to win64
>
> If you are compiling the 2.1.1 or greater branch of fpc you can just do:
>
> ```
> $ make all OS_TARGET=win64 CPU_TARGET=x86_64
> ```
>
> and then
>
> ```
> $ make crossinstall OS_TARGET=win64 CPU_TARGET=x86_64
> ```

which, if you follow, just gives a few thousand errors:

[image]

The common suggestion is to abandon the Lazarus IDE, [altogether](http://www.gotwavs.com/0038067694/MP3S/Movies/Airplane/ap12.mp3), and use a fork known as [CodeTyphoon](http://www.pilotlogic.com/sitejoom/index.php/codetyphon). Downloading that 500 MB, and installing it, i couldn't find an IDE anywhere:

[image]

Which is confusing, because i *thought* CodeTyphoon was a Pascal Visual Programming Environment.

## Before i go on

Before i go randomly stumbling around, downloading gigabytes of stuff, let me just ask straight out:

> Can Lazarus 64-bit for Windows compile to 64-bit for Windows?

Is there a 64-bit Lazarus for Windows, that can create 64-bit Windows binaries? Am i missing something, or is that functionality not in there yet?

And if the ability is in there, at least could someone commiserate that my confusion is understandable?

Comment: There seems to be a problem with the 64-bit link on the site. Visit [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Windows%2064%20bits/Lazarus%201.2/) for the 64bit IDE. Down below very same page, text suggests not to use 64bit IDE and not to produce 64bit applications.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz That makes it even more confusing, as it says *"The Lazarus team recommends to use the 32-bit Version of Lazarus, even for generating 64 bit applications."* - which is something it doesn't seem to be able to do.

Comment: In the black console screen above you are not running the make packaged by FPC, but the one packaged with Delphi. Check your configuration.

Comment: (and by that I mean that FPC is before Delphi in %PATH% if you run Lazarus e.g. by creating a batchfile that does PATH d:\lazarus\fpc\bin\i386-win32;%PATH before starting lazarus.

Comment: TLDR; I used `ShowMessage(inttostr(sizeof(pointer)));` to determin if the exe is 64bit or 32bit :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following is from `README.txt` files on the SourceForge download pages (http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Windows%2032%20bits/Lazarus%201.2/ and http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Windows%2064%20bits/Lazarus%201.2/).  However, those readme.txt files are apparently not included in the actual installation.

I have verified that installing the plug-in allows you to build a 64-bit application.

Two things:

1. there is an add-on for building Win64 applications in the 32-bit Lazarus IDE:

> - Add-On for building 64bit Windows applications:
>
>   [lazarus-1.2.0-fpc-2.6.2-cross-x86_64-win64-win32.exe](http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Windows%2032%20bits/Lazarus%201.2/lazarus-1.2.0-fpc-2.6.2-cross-x86_64-win64-win32.exe/download)
>
>   This file can be installed as add-on to the 32 bit Lazarus IDE (on Systems with Windows 32 or 64 bit), if you wish to develop for
>     64bit Windows too. If you install this on a 64bit Windows PC together
>     with the 32 bit Lazarus IDE, you will also able to debug 64 bit
>     applications.

1. the link to the 64-bit Lazarus IDE on the Lazarus homepage is incorrect (it points to the Win32 version).  The link should be:

   http://sourceforge.net/projects/lazarus/files/Lazarus%20Windows%2064%20bits/Lazarus%201.2/lazarus-1.2.0-fpc-2.6.2-win64.exe/download

If you use the 64-bit IDE you'll need a similar (but different) plugin to build 32-bit binaries.

Comment: That certainly was the confusion. What was supposed to be the 64-bit edition was actually the 32-bit edition. I didn't know if the same download contained both, and they used some fancy things. In reality it was just a mistake on their part. And adding the 64-bit addon solved my actual problem.

Comment: 64-bit IDE's are not recommended with FPC-2.6.x. These FPC versions don't support SEH, and plugins using SEH might crash the open file dialog.

Comment: Ian: note the bottom line of your first image in your post. There is a link to the "other" there afaik. In general I don't recommend CodeTyphon. The added layer is very thin, support is vocal but no too strong, and the project is not really transparant